# Final field initialization in a subclass

Tags: java, initialization

Strange, but I can't find a duplicate for this question.
I have a superclass with overrideMe() method and a subclass that overrides it.
Is the final field really initialized before the subclass constructor is called?
As I can see from the output, it is.

Here's the output:
Superclass constr
str value: someValue
Subclass constr
str value: someValue

Could you please explain this to me?
I thought that instance variables are initialized within the constructor call but not before it.

Here's the code:

```
public class Test {
  public Test() {
    System.out.println("Superclass constr");
    overrideMe();
  }

  public void overrideMe() {
  }
}

class Ext extends Test {
  private final String str = "someValue";

  public Ext() {
    System.out.println("Subclass constr");
  }

  @Override
  public void overrideMe() {
    System.out.println("str value: " + str);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Ext test = new Ext();
    test.overrideMe();
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**
if I declasre str field as non-final, the subclass call of it in the constructor returns null as I expect.

Comment: Every constructor calls `super` (or `this` which calls `super`) first so the super class is always initialised first. (Except `java.lang.Object` which has no super)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes fields are initialized before the constructor is called, and this starts with the upper class before the overloading one.

Here's a general presentation : http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_java/TIJ306_014.htm

Comment: [JLS 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5) for more clarity

Comment: Oops, that was a really silly question :)
the only thing I still can't get is why the final field is not initialized to null at first.

Comment: @iozee a final field is never changed. It can't be initialized at null and change value after that.

Comment: Ok, so if I split the declaration and initialization of final str field (init it in Ext's constructor) I would see null at the superclass overrideMe() call?

Comment: This answer is actually wrong, Adrian Liu's answer is the correct one (the difference being that **fields of subclasses are not initialized** before the super constructor is called).

Answer (score 1):

The final field with initializer will be replaced with the const string by compiler, that's why it seemed the field is initialized even before the super constructor returned.

If the final field is blank inited, which means it is inited in the child class's constructor, then of course the super constructor will see a null.

If the field is neither final nor static, and an initializer is provided, then it will be inited after the super constructor and before the child constructor.